# SharePoint Online - list on premise AD users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-server

We use an on-premise AD (Windows Server 2012) with Azure sync and Office 365, hence have SharePoint Online available.

The goal is to list and update all AD users (name, email, birthday) in a SharePoint list, not bidirectional though.

My assumption was that this data is somehow accessible without the need to do anything serversided, since it's all in Azure and 365.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great article at https://en.share-gate.com/blog/corporate-directory-sharepoint-search that shows how this can be built using the content by search functionality. This approach works really well and gives an easy-to-use system that will automatically be updated as new members are added to the staff list, and can allow easy filtering based on the additional metadata associated with each person.

The article (not mine!) provides the required code to get it up and running.